# How do I use create and update in one method?

Tags: laravel

I have a subscription table with a `subscription_status` field. When a user pays for a subscription he enters a transaction code which is used for verification. The system then checks if the user had a subscription. If he did not have any subscription, he is added to the database. If he had a subscription the system is meant to edit his record.

This is the code I am using:

```
public function store(Request $request, $user_id)
{
    $transaction_code = $request->transaction_code;
    $email = Auth::user()->email;
    $user = Auth::user();
    $user_id = $user->id;
    $phone_number = DB::table('profiles')->where('user_id', $user_id)->value('phone_number');
    //$quotation_title = DB::table('quotations')->where('id',$id)->value('quotation_title');

    $url = "https://education254.com/wp-admin/helbportal/api/results.php";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $paymentdata = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $pc = json_decode($paymentdata, true);
    $collection = collect($pc);
    $result = $collection->firstWhere('transaction_code', $transaction_code);

    if ($result['transaction_amount'] == 50.00 && $result['transactor_number'] == 254729054514) {
        $subscriptionstatus = 1;
    } else {
        $subscriptionstatus = 0;
    }

    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    $user_data = DB::table('subscriptions')->where('user_id', $user_id)->get();

    if ($user_data = null) {
        $subscription = new Subscription;

        $subscription->user_id = $user_id;
        $subscription->transaction_code = $request->transaction_code;
        $subscription->subscription_status = $subscriptionstatus;
        $subscription->subscription_endtime = Carbon::now()->addMonths(1);
        $subscription->save();

        return view('subscriptions.success');
    } else {
        $subscription = Subscription::findOrFail($user_id);

        $subscription->user_id = $user_id;
        $subscription->transaction_code = $request->transaction_code;
        $subscription->subscription_status = $subscriptionstatus;
        $subscription->subscription_endtime = Carbon::now()->addMonths(1);
        $subscription->save();

        return view('subscriptions.success');
    }
}
```

I am having having trouble updating the records as I am getting this error:

> "Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\SubscriptionController::store(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected

Comment: Why are you passing the `$user_id` to the method when you're just getting it from `Auth::user()` anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not pass `$user_id` as a parameter of function. You can get auth user by `Auth::user()->id`.
Also, there are few changes in code that you required.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $transaction_code = $request->transaction_code;
    $email = Auth::user()->email;
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $phone_number = DB::table('profiles')->where('user_id', $user_id)->value('phone_number');
    //$quotation_title = DB::table('quotations')->where('id',$id)->value('quotation_title');

    $url = "https://education254.com/wp-admin/helbportal/api/results.php";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $paymentdata = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $pc = json_decode($paymentdata, true);
    $collection = collect($pc);
    $result = $collection->firstWhere('transaction_code', $transaction_code);

    if ($result['transaction_amount'] == 50.00 && $result['transactor_number'] == 254729054514) {
        $subscriptionstatus = 1;
    } else {
        $subscriptionstatus = 0;
    }

    $user_data = DB::table('subscriptions')->where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
    $subscription = new Subscription;
    if ($user_data == null) {

        $subscription->user_id = $user_id;
        $subscription->transaction_code = $request->transaction_code;
        $subscription->subscription_status = $subscriptionstatus;
        $subscription->subscription_endtime = Carbon::now()->addMonths(1);
        $subscription->save();

        return view('subscriptions.success');
    } else {
        $subscription = Subscription::findOrFail($user_id);

        $data = ['transaction_code '=> $request->transaction_code, 'subscription_status '=> $subscriptionstatus, 'subscription_endtime'=> Carbon::now()->addMonths(1)];

        $subscription ->where('user_id', $user_id)->update($data);
        return view('subscriptions.success');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove $user_id from method signature

```
//...
public function store(Request $request)
//...
```